# Is it possible multiple tab bar controller in an application in objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller

I want to switch different tab bar controller with root view controller's buttons. I mean that I have several buttons and this buttons must have different tab bar controller. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible if you have a navigationcontroller as a parent of both tabbarcontrolllers.

However I would advise against such an UI as it will most likely be confusing to the end user.

Why would you want to use this approach?

Answer (score 1):

have a look at this: [iOs Human Interface Guideline](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html)

I think that it's not recommended. For example:

> Use a tab bar to give users access to different perspectives on the same set of data or different subtasks related to the overall function of your app. When you use a tab bar, follow these guidelines:
>
> Don’t use a tab bar to give users controls that act on elements in the current mode or screen. If you need to provide controls for your users, use a toolbar instead (for usage guidelines, see “Toolbar”).
>
> In general, use a tab bar to organize information at the application level. A tab bar is well-suited for use in the main app view because it’s a good way to flatten your information hierarchy and provide access to several peer information categories or modes at one time.