# How to cast value of type UITabBar to other UITabBar?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, uitabbarcontroller

I have 2 tab bar
the first tab bar is down to view and the second tab bar is up to view. 
I want to change VC in my first bar item (first tab bar) with my Button to my second tab bar item,

`(tabBarController as! AccountTopTabBarViewController).AccountCustomTabBar.changeTabIndex(1)`

this code is my first tabbar and work it just for cast value in first tab bar,but for2 tab bar not work :/  and gived to me this error

Comment: `Could not cast value of type 'MyApp.MainTabBar' (0x100346d28) to 'MyApp.AccountTopTabBarViewController' (0x100344178).
(lldb)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977639/is-it-possible-multiple-tab-bar-controller-in-an-application-in-objective-c